# How to display output in servlet when invoking a method dynamically

Tags: java, servlets, reflection

I am trying to dynamically load a class and invoke one of its methods from my Servlet.

In my Servlet I have the following code :

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

try {
       Class<?> obj = Class.forName(myclassName);           
       Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod(myMethodName);
       String returnValue = (String) method.invoke(obj, null);
       out.println(returnValue);

 } 
catch(Exception e){}
```

And in the class I have :

```
public class StudentClass {

  public String index()
  {
    return "This is From StudentClass";
  }
}
```

The problem is when I run my application it does not display anything. I am expecting to get `This is From StudentClass` as output , which basically `index` method of the class is returning.

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do u get any exception? Don't just eatt the exceptio, try to print the stacktrace in your Exception block?

Comment: @Juned Ahsan Thanks for your reply. I don't get any exception. I have `e.printStackTrace();` in my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `invoke` usage is wrong:

```
Class<?> obj = Class.forName(myclassName); // this return a Class, not an instance
Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod(myMethodName);
String returnValue = (String) method.invoke(obj, null);
```

Proper use would be something like:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(myclassName);           
Object obj = clazz.newInstance(); // this give you a StudentClass instance
Method method = clazz.getMethod(myMethodName);
String returnValue = (String) method.invoke(obj);
```

see also [`Class.forName(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) and [`Method.invoke(Object, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) and [this tutorial on reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working perfectly now. I will go through with the tutorials now. thanks.